# Connecting to a WiFi through an Android application

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

I wish to create an application, that detects the available wifi connections in the vicinity, and then connects to them. What I have done till now, is that I created a ListView that lists the available wifi connections, and then I created a LongItemClick dialog box, that shows the SSID and the BSSID of the network, and asks for the password. Now, I wish to connect to one of the networks, independent of what kind of network it is, it might be WEP, WPA or Open too. I am unable to get an overview of how should I connect to them. Can anyone help me with this ? I searched all available answers, and I didn't find any answer, that could help me do this!

I try the above thing by the below method. I create a list view of all the available wi-fi networks in the vicinity, and then I try to show the connection info on long press, and give an option to connect to the clicked wi-fi network via click.

Code:

```
package com.example.random;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;    
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;    

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;    
import android.content.Intent;     
import android.content.IntentFilter;    
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;    
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;   
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.Protocol;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;   
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;    
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;    
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;    
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;    
import android.widget.TextView;    
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
 {      
    WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
//    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;
    final Context context = this;
    EditText pass;
    String checkPassword = null;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                connectToWifi(arg2);
            }



                private void connectToWifi(final int position)
                        {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connect);
                    dialog.setTitle("Connect to Network");
                    TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID);
                    TextView textBSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textBSSID);
                    TextView capabilities = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textCapabilities);

                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                    pass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
                    textSSID.setText(results.get(position).SSID);
                    textBSSID.setText(results.get(position).BSSID);
                    capabilities.setText(results.get(position).capabilities);
//                                      
                    // if button is clicked, connect to the network;
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            checkPassword = pass.getText().toString();
                            finallyConnect(checkPassword);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        private void finallyConnect(String checkPassword) {
                            String networkSSID = results.get(position).SSID;
                            String networkPass = checkPassword;

                            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                            wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
                            wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);

                            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                            //remember id
                            int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                            wifiManager.disconnect();
                            wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                            wifiManager.reconnect();



                            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
                            conf.SSID = "\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"";
                            conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
                            WifiManager wifiManager1 = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                            wifiManager1.addNetwork(conf);

//                          List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager1.getConfiguredNetworks();
//                          for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
//                              if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
//                                   wifiManager1.disconnect();
//                                   
//                                  wifiManager1.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
//                                  if(wifiManager1.reconnect()){
////                                    int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
////                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ipAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), networkSSID + " "+ "Connection successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                              
//                                  }
//                                  else{
//                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                  }
//                                  
//                                   break;
//                                         
//                              }
//                          }

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
       });

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showWifiSettings(arg2);
                return true;
            }

            private void showWifiSettings(int arg2) {
                showDialogOfOptions(arg2);
                    }

            private void showDialogOfOptions(int arg2) {
                // Create a custom Dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Network details");
                TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID);
                TextView textBSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textBSSID);
                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                textSSID.setText(results.get(arg2).SSID);
                textBSSID.setText(results.get(arg2).BSSID);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
              }
            });

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }   

        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
    }

//    protected void connectionStatus(String password) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      
//      
//  }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {


        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try 
        {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) 
            {   
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID.toString()+ results.get(size).capabilities.toString());

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            }


           }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }         
    }    
}
```

The application is running fine, but it does not connect to any of the Wifi networks. 
Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a ScanResult to determine the encryption type of the wifi configuration picked by the user.

The code below works fine in my app, except the EAP encryption type is not handled yet.

And one more thing, the method mWifiManager.reassociate( ) and mWifiManager.reconnect( ) seems work the same for me.

```
 private void connectWifi( ScanResult sr , String pwd )
    {

    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration( );
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear( );
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear( );
    config.allowedKeyManagement.clear( );
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear( );
    config.allowedProtocols.clear( );
    config.SSID = "\"" + sr.SSID + "\"";

    if( sr.capabilities.contains( "WEP" ) )
    {
        config.hiddenSSID = true;

        if( pwd.matches( "[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}" ) )
        {
        config.preSharedKey = pwd;
        }
        else
        {
        config.preSharedKey = '"' + pwd + '"';
        }

        config.allowedKeyManagement.set( KeyMgmt.NONE );
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set( WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN );
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set( WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED );
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP );
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP );
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40 );
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104 );
        config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;

    }
    else if( sr.capabilities.contains( "PSK" ) )
    {
        config.preSharedKey = "\"" + pwd + "\"";
        config.hiddenSSID = true;
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set( WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN );
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP );
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set( WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK );
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP );
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP );
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set( WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP );
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    }
    else if( sr.capabilities.contains( "EAP" ) )
    {

    }
    else
    {
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set( KeyMgmt.NONE );
    }

    int wcgID = mWifiManager.addNetwork( config );
    mWifiManager.enableNetwork( wcgID , true );
    //  mWifiManager.reconnect( );
    mWifiManager.reassociate( );
    mWifiManager.saveConfiguration( );
    }






private final OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener( )
    {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView< ? > parent , View view , int position , long id )
    {
        final ScanResult sr = sortWifiList.get( position );
        if( !mWifiInfo.getSSID( ).equals( "\"" + sr.SSID + "\"" ) )
        {
        mConnectState = NO_CONNECT;
        refreshConnectViews( );
        }
        connectImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById( R.id.wifi_connected );
        connectTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.wifi_info_state );
        connectTextView.setTag( sr );
        //      connectTextView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        //      connectImage.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        //      connectTextView.setText( R.string.wifi_connecting );
        //      connectImage.setBackground( refreshDrawable );
        //      connectImage.startAnimation( animation );
        //      TextView wifiSsid = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.wifi_ssid );
        //      wifiSsid.setPadding( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
        if( !mWifiInfo.getSSID( ).equals( "\"" + sr.SSID + "\"" ) )
        {
        if( hasLocked( sr.capabilities ) )
        {
            mWifiConfiguration = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks( );
            WifiConfiguration wc = hasSaved( sr );
            // saved wifi , connect directly
            if( wc != null )
            {
            connectWifi( wc );
            }
            else
            {
            enterPasswordDialog( view , sr );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            connectWifi( sr , "" );
        }
        }
        autoRefresh = false;
        mScanner.pause( );
    }
    };


    private boolean hasLocked( String capabilities )
    {
    if( capabilities.contains( "WEP" ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if( capabilities.contains( "PSK" ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if( capabilities.contains( "EAP" ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }

private void connectWifi( WifiConfiguration wc )
{
    int wcgID = mWifiManager.addNetwork( wc );
    mWifiManager.enableNetwork( wcgID , true );
    //  mWifiManager.reconnect( );
    mWifiManager.reassociate( );
}
```

Comment: What does `if( pwd.matches( "[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}" )` this statement check for ?

Comment: What if even the above method doesn't work ? Can you suggest where am I erring ?

Comment: For some more information, my capabilities tab reads as `[WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPS][ESS]`

Comment: Yes, it is a little tricky to test these codes,I spend a lot of time to make it works fine.I suggest you establish a wifi ap by yourself with no encryption and other encrption types to test seperately

Comment: Is there a need of a separate handler, or a thread, or maybe Async Task for this, as this is getting connected to a network, so that might be overloading the Thread ?
Do you wish to know the LogCat when I try to connect to the above configured network using the password?

Comment: [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPS][ESS] goes to PSK code branch, and WPA/WPA2 is most widely used nowadys. Maybe you should test the code using a none encrytion wifi ap and then step by step ,go through all the conditions.

Comment: Fine, I will try. What about using a separate thread? Do you think its needed ?

Comment: And, till when can you reply back, I need this pretty urgently!

Comment: I don't think a thread or asyncTask is needed cause I invoke the method in the main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56589/discussion-between-bumblebee-and-froyohuang).