# Get IP Address of connected Wi fi in Android application

Tags: android, android-wifi

When I get the IP Address via the command `wifiManager.getIpAddress()` the app shuts down. Can someone tell me the reason why ?
I am obtaining the desired ip  address when I use the method at the bottom, but in the code for the same, when I try displaying the Ip address directly, it gives me an error

EDIT-

```
package com.example.socketserverclient;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    final Context context = this;
    WifiManager wifi;
    TextView ipAddress, BSSID;
    Button getIP;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

//      String IpAddress = getLocalIpAddress();
        ipAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textIpAddress);
        BSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBSSID);
        getIP = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
//      ipAddress.setText(IpAddress);
        getIP.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String IpAddress = getLocalIpAddress();
//              ipAddress.setText(IpAddress);
            }

        });
    }
    private String getLocalIpAddress() {

        WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        //gets the Ip address in hex form, We need to convert it to integer and then finally to string to display it 

        int myIp = myWifiInfo.getIpAddress(); 
        BSSID.setText(myIp);
        int intMyIp3 = myIp/0x1000000;
        int intMyIp3mod = myIp%0x1000000;

        int intMyIp2 = intMyIp3mod/0x10000;
        int intMyIp2mod = intMyIp3mod%0x10000;

        int intMyIp1 = intMyIp2mod/0x100;
        int intMyIp0 = intMyIp2mod%0x100;

        ipAddress.setText(String.valueOf(intMyIp0) + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp1)
                            + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp2)
                            + "." + String.valueOf(intMyIp3)
                );


    return null;
        }

}
```

LOG CAT:

```
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063): Process: com.example.socketserverclient, PID: 21063
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xd01a8c0
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at com.example.socketserverclient.MainActivity.getLocalIpAddress(MainActivity.java:56)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at com.example.socketserverclient.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:48)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at com.example.socketserverclient.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-01 14:22:44.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21063):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Yeah @PurpleDroid, sure..Gimme a sec!

Comment: Did you give the related permissions?

Comment: @Aniruddha - Permissions have been given accordingly!

Comment: What Device do you use?

Comment: are you connected to a router.?

Comment: And can you give us the rest of the code?

Comment: @mapo - Ya, using a router, I just want to get my current working IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
BSSID.setText(myIp);
```

The problem is you are trying to pass an `int` in the `setText` method of your `TextView`.

In short you are calling method `setText(int resid)` instead of `setText(CharSequence text)`

So Android will try to look for the resource which you passed in the `setText` i.e. `myIp` which does not exist and you will get a `ResourcesNotFoundException`

Change the code from

```
BSSID.setText(myIp);
```

to

```
BSSID.setText(String.valueOf(myIp));
```

Comment: -Fine, the answer worked. Can someone tell me a solution to a previous problem as well ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503076/connecting-to-a-wifi-through-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddr = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
```

with given permissions in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: `ipAddr` as per the solution suggested by you, will give me the ipAddress, but how to use it further is an issue. Like, if I try setting a `TextView` to display the above message, it gives the error as shown in LOGCAT

Comment: Fine @purpleDroid, solution worked, can someone tell me a solution to a previous value as well ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503076/connecting-to-a-wifi-through-an-android-application

Comment: @BumbleBee I was in a meeting. Saw the comment now. And saw that issue is solved :) happy coding

Comment: Need your help on the wifi topic again. Can you just look at my previous posted question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503076/connecting-to-a-wifi-through-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected String wifiIpAddress(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();

    // Convert little-endian to big-endianif needed
    if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
        ipAddress = Integer.reverseBytes(ipAddress);
    }

    byte[] ipByteArray = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();

    String ipAddressString;
    try {
        ipAddressString = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipByteArray).getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Log.e("WIFIIP", "Unable to get host address.");
        ipAddressString = null;
    }

    return ipAddressString;
}
```

And give this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Call this method from onCreate like this

```
String str = wifiIpAddress(getApplicationContext());
your_Textview.setText(str);
```

**EDIT**

Change  `BSSID.setText(myIp);`

to

`BSSID.setText(myIp + "");`

Comment: Can someone tell me a solution to a previous problem as well ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503076/connecting-to-a-wifi-through-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the IP Address function. You have a problem finding a resource at the memory address: #0xd01a8c0

Check whether the resource is set or not. As in the LogCat Error it should be a string in the strings.xml

**edit:**

Replace `BSSID.setText(myIp);` with `BSSID.setText(myIp + "");`

Comment: How do I check, whether the following resource is set or not ?

Comment: Check: at com.example.socketserverclient.MainActivity.getLocalIpAddress(MainActivity.java:56). There is a setText which causes the error

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution worked. Can someone tell me a solution to a previous problem as well ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503076/connecting-to-a-wifi-through-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Line 56:
BSSID.setText(myIp);

myIp is an integer, and for TextView's setText method , according to the SDK document:

```
final void setText(int resid)
```

So android will consider myIp a resource id which it cannot find this resource by the value of myIp.The simplest way to correct this is:

```
BSSID.setText(""+myIp);
```

which you actually invoke this method of TextView:

```
final void setText(CharSequence text)
```